# Trying to install Intel Xeon Phi Driver on Centos 7

Tags: drivers, xeon-phi

I tried to install and Intel Xeon Phi Driver. But it seems to have some problems. As the message just say "failed to load" and I dont know why, I hoped someone has experience with this and could tell me the trick.

I basically downloaded the source from the Intel-Homepage and installed the rpm.

```
20:01:20 mice fprintd: ** Message: No devices in use, exit
Nov 17 20:03:18 mice systemd: Starting Intel(R) MPSS control service...
Nov 17 20:03:18 mice mpss: Loading MIC module: [FAILED]
Nov 17 20:03:18 mice systemd: mpss.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 17 20:03:18 mice systemd: Failed to start Intel(R) MPSS control service.
Nov 17 20:03:18 mice systemd: Unit mpss.service entered failed state.
Nov 17 20:10:01 mice systemd: Created slice user-0.slice.
Nov 17 20:10:01 mice systemd: Starting Session 11 of user root.
Nov 17 20:10:01 mice systemd: Started Session 11 of user root.
```